# Java runtime getRuntime exec not returning desired results

Tags: java

I have the below code that is sorting contents of my file based on timestamp but it's not working. If I pass the unix command directly, ie `cat /var/test/mylog/output.txt | sort -n`, it works perfectly but it won't execute in my Java code.

```
private void writeResponseEntityToFile(List<String> response) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Path out = Paths.get("/var/log/logstream/output.txt");
    Files.write(out, response, Charset.defaultCharset());
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /var/test/mylog/output.txt | sort -n");
    process.waitFor();
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't read and sort the file using java code?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `Runtime.exec` executes the given file (`cat`) directly, without using the shell. When you type `cat /var/test/mylog/output.txt | sort -n` into the shell, it is the shell that does the piping, i.e. it creates a pipe, executes `cat /var/test/mylog/output.txt` sending its output to the pipe, and concurrently also executes `sort -n`, giving it the pipe output as its input. You can execute a shell command like that from Java's `Runtime` by executing `bash` or a similar shell. You should use the form of `exec` that takes an array of String, and pass the command `bash` as the first argument:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    new String[]{"bash", "-c", "cat /var/test/mylog/output.txt | sort -n"});
```

The next thing to do is to think about what you want to do with the output of that command. Use `Process.getInputStream()` for that; e.g.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    new String[]{"bash", "-c", "cat /var/test/mylog/output.txt | sort -n"});
if (process.waitFor() != 0) {
    System.err.println("Something went wrong")
} else {
    String output = new String(process.getInputStream().readAllBytes())
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nope, didn't work. It's hung, and won't execute.

Comment: Sorry, the command was wrong, I've just corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run a SHELL command from Java, you need either to run `bash` subprocess before `cat | sort` as indicated by @k314159 or change your command to regular executable (assuming sort is on your path):

```
sort -n /var/test/mylog/output.txt
```

Note: you must handle stdout + stderr streams before `process.waitFor()` as this can lead to the process freezing when the output of either stream is unread and exceeds the default buffer size. Streams are easier to control with `ProcessBuilder`, you can redirect to file(s), or merge stderr to stdout (thus avoiding need for background thread reader) as in this example:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"sort","-n", "/var/test/mylog/output.txt"});
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = pb.start();
process.getInputStream().transferTo(System.out);
int rc = process.waitFor();
if (rc != 0)
    throw new RuntimeException("Sort failed rc="+rc);
```